# Transferring svyset from Stata to R

Tags: r, stata, weighted

I have a survey project in Stata but I want to transfer this into R.

This code in Stata sets the weighting:

```
svyset sitename [pweight=wgt], poststrata(strata) postweight(popsize)
```

and then this code produces the final weighted proportions of gender and also gender in two different age groups:

```
svy: prop gender

svy, subpop(if agegroup==1): prop gender

svy, subpop(if agegroup==2): prop gender
```

I have been trying to use the `survey` package in R to produce the same results and although it is weighting the figures they are not the same as the results in Stata.

I have tried a few different methods of creating a survey design object:

```
survey_design <- svydesign(ids = ~sitename, strata = ~strata, weights = ~wgt, data = pc_2022_data, fpc = ~popsize, nest=T)
```

I used this code to produce the gender proportion:

```
prop_table <- svytable(~pvgender, survey_design)

print(prop_table)

weighted_prop_table <- prop_table / sum(prop_table) * 100

print(weighted_prop_table)
```

I am trying to get the same proportion results out of both Stata and R.

Comment: There may be a simple answer from someone familiar with both. Otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example gives important advice.